# Flex 4 syntax in actionscript ...?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

One (dumb) question:

Is it possible to use flex 4 syntax declaration inside of a actionscript method?
For example, something like that:

```
private function buildContent() : void {

     <s:Label id="aLabel">

}
```

Thanks.

P.S. I couldn't find any reference about this, so i think it is not possible :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sorry, not possible. Just like you can't put HTML in JavaScript (without it being a string).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax isn't "Flex 4 syntax" but "MXML".

You can achieve what you want, while writing:

```
private function buildContent() : void {
     var label:Label = new Label();
}
```

The syntax `<s:Label />` represents an `spark:components:Label` object.